# HTML5 video in portrait in fullscreen mode in cordova app is stretched on Android devices

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, html5-video

When I play a video filmed in a landscape orientation on my android device and enter fullscreen the device stays in portrait mode and stretches the video horribly.

Is there a way to force the video not to stretch in portrait mode when entering fullscreen? But to remain in landscape orientation, and have black borders top and bottom.

[image: Normal aspect ratio]

[image: Stretched in portrait mode]

```
      <video class="media-video" 
  video-directive item="$ctrl.item" 
  ng-src="{{$ctrl.item.videoUrl | trustUrl}}" 
  preload="auto" 
  controls
    poster="{{$ctrl.item.video.thumbnail_url}}">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
```

Comment: Will the be any help ? https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/01/zooming-and-rotating-for-video-in-html5-and-css3/

Comment: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation Cordova has a core plugin that allows you to set the orientation of the screen. Could this be of help?

Comment: Thanks @MattBrewerton - but no. I'm already using that plugin. I don't want to set the orientation, I want it to stay in portrait but keep the ratio of the video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a similar project which play video in a cordova app in android and my video doesn't stretch in portrait fullscreen :

[image]

I don't use any codova plugin. It's the natural behavior.
Maybe you force this behavior with some CSS like a property height: 100%. Or something like.

This is the link of my video player directive : https://github.com/Dammmien/Planete-cine/blob/master/src/js/directives/videoPlayer.js

Comment: hmm interesting. Are you using an HTML5 video tag like me?

Comment: Yes, I updated my answer with the link of my video player directive